# Determining values based on the count of that item in

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. ticket & ticketlist.
The sold out column in the ticket table needs to be 1 if that item is sold out.
Table ticket needs to be soldout when the count for that item in table ticketlist is 2.

```
ticket
ticketid, quantity, soldout  
21          2             1 

ticketlist
ticketlistid, ticketid          
3                 21
4                 21
```

The logic is:

soldout should be '1' if ticket.quantity - (COUNT(ticketlist.ticketlistid) WHERE ticket.ticketid = ticketlist.ticketlistid) > 0

This is the MySQL that I tried

```
   UPDATE ticket
    SET soldout = '1'
    WHERE quantity - (SELECT ticket.ticketid, COUNT(ticketlist.ticketlistid)
            FROM ticket, ticketlist
            WHERE ticket.ticketid = ticketlist.ticketid) > '0';
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Always good to post the errors you got.

Comment: "Table ticket needs to be soldout when the count for that item in table ticketlist is 2." : I assume you say 2 here because the quantity is 2?

Comment: Alright Kerry, Will post the error

Comment: Yes Mark, 'soldout' in table 'ticket' should be '1' (meaning true), because the count for that item in table 'ticketlist' is '2', and the quantity for that item in table 'ticket' is 2

Comment: I saw an error in my logic. Something is sold out when the (quantity) - (quantity sold) = 0 So, the query should end with '= 0' and not '>0'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your subselect:

- You should only return one column.
- Don't select the same table you already have from your update.

You probably also want to set `sold_out` to one when `quantity - (SELECT ...) <= 0`, rather than `> 0` as you are currently doing.

Change the query to this:

```
UPDATE ticket
SET soldout = '1'
WHERE quantity - (
    SELECT COUNT(ticketlist.ticketlistid)
    FROM ticketlist
    WHERE ticket.ticketid = ticketlist.ticketid
) > 0;
```

Also your database is denormalized. You are storing information in one table that can be derived from the data in another table. This redundancy can cause errors if the two ever get out of sync. I'd recommend only doing this if you need it for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You're better of [implementing this as a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html), otherwise risk the soldout number being out of sync.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_tickets AS
    SELECT t.ticketid,
           t.quantity,
           COUNT(*) AS sold,
           CASE 
             WHEN t.quantity = COUNT(*) THEN 1 
             WHEN t.quantity < COUNT(*) THEN -1 -- oversold
             ELSE 0 
           END AS soldout
      FROM TICKET t
 LEFT JOIN TICKETLIST tl ON tl.ticketid = t.ticketid
  GROUP BY t.ticketid, t.quantity
```

Comment: +1 for the view idea. There doesn't seem any point storing state information in one table for information that is already available in another table.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is this:

```
(SELECT ticket.ticketid, COUNT(ticketlist.ticketlistid)
            FROM ticket, ticketlist
            WHERE ticket.ticketid = ticketlist.ticketid)
```

You are testing the result of that query against `"> 0"` however, it returns ticketid and count. You need to removed ticket.ticketid.

Comment: The `> 0` comparison also won't catch if more tickets have been sold than the quantity allotted for the show.

Comment: Yes, it actually needs to be = 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `ticket`
SET `soldout` = 1
WHERE `ticketid` IN ( 
    SELECT `ticketid` FROM `ticketlist` GROUP BY `ticketid` HAVING COUNT(`ticketlistid`) = 2 )
```